# Getting 'The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with same key value for is already being tracked' with AsNoTracking()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm creating my Telegram bot using Entity Framework Core. I have these models:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Chat> Chats { get; set;} = new List<Chat>();
    public ICollection<Team> CreatedTeams { get; set; } = new List<Team>();
    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; } = new List<Team>();
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ChatId { get; set; }
    public Chat Chat { get; set; }
    public int? CreatorId { get; set; }
    public User Creator { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}
```

When I handle incoming messages, I check if a `User` with the same `UserId` exists in DB. If it exists, then I just get it, if not - create new one on a base of `Telegram User` and return it.

```
public async Task<User> GetNewOrExistingUserAsync(Telegram.Bot.Types.User telegramUser)
{
    var user = this.GetUserByUserId(telegramUser.Id);

    if (user is null)
    {
        await this.userRepository.AddAsync((User)telegramUser);
        return this.GetUserByUserId(telegramUser.Id);
    }

    return user;
}

private User GetUserByUserId(long userId)
{
    return this.userRepository.GetAll()
            .Include(user => user.Chats)
            .Include(user => user.Teams)
            .Include(user => user.CreatedTeams)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault(user => user.UserId == userId);
 }
```

After that I get `Team` by name specified in message:

```
public Team GetChatTeamByName(string name, long chatId)
{
    return this.teamRepository.GetAll()
         .Include(team => team.Creator)
         .Include(team => team.Users)
         .AsNoTracking()
         .FirstOrDefault(team => team.Chat.ChatId == chatId && team.Name.Equals(name));
}
```

And finally I add `user` to `team` (I check, if it already exists in `team`, but I receive this error even without this check):

```
team.Users.Add(user);
await this.teamRepository.UpdateAsync(team);
```

Here I get this error: '*The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked*'. `UpdateAsync()` uses `Entities.Update()` method and saves changes. Error occurs after `Entities.Update()` call. I do not understand, where it starts tracking user - as you can see, I use `AsNoTracking()` in all related queries. I could assume, that it starts tracking after adding new user, but error occurs even when user is already in DB.

I've tried to use `Entry<User>(user).State = EntityState.Detached;` as people suggest, right before adding user to team, or after it, but error is the same. The context in my ASP app is `Transient`, but this error occurs even if it `Scoped`. Could you help me please with it? Or are there any other ways to add `user` to `team` without calling `Update()` method?

The whole method is:

```
public async Task<Message> AddUserToTeamAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Message message)
{
    var user = await this.userService.GetNewOrExistingUserAsync(message.From);

    var teamName = message.Text.SplitToWords()[1];
    var team = this.teamService.GetChatTeamByName(teamName, message.Chat.Id);

    team.Users.Add(user);
    await this.teamRepository.UpdateAsync(team);
    .....
}
```

Update.`GetAll()` method:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
    return this.Entities;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to fully comprehend what `AsNoTracking` does: It explicitly disconnects the entity from the database. So if you want to `Update` that entity, you shouldn't disconnect it in the first place.

It's a relational database. If you want to add an existing `user` to a `team`, you need to track the existing object. Else the database will try to create a new one with *exactly* the same values, and there will be a collision.

**DEBATABLE** Side note: why are you using `Include`, instead of lazy loading? We are running several large application at my company and almost never have to use `Include`.

EDIT: I did a small test

```cs
namespace UserTeams
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Team> CreatedTeams { get; set; } = new List<Team>();
        public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; } = new List<Team>();
    }

    public class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? CreatorId { get; set; }
        public User Creator { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace UserTeams
{
    internal class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(user => user.Teams).WithMany(team => team.Users);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(user => user.CreatedTeams).WithOne(team => team.Creator);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasOne(team => team.Creator)
                .WithMany(user => user.CreatedTeams)
                .HasForeignKey(team => team.CreatorId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasMany(team => team.Users).WithMany(user => user.Teams);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using UserTeams;

using (var myContext = new MyContext())
{
    myContext.Users.Add(new User
    {
        UserId = 123,
    });

    myContext.Teams.Add(new Team
    {
        Name = "myTeam",
    });

    myContext.SaveChanges();
}

using (var myContext = new MyContext())
{
    var user = myContext.Users.First(u => u.UserId == 123);

    var team = myContext.Teams.First(t => t.Name == "myTeam");

    team.Users.Add(user);
    user.Teams.Add(team);
    myContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get no collisions.
[image]

Comment: Well, I start using AsNoTracking() after this error ocurred - in almost all related questions the answer was 'use it'. And It sounds logically to me - if the error is in tracking entity, then untracking will help.

Comment: If I remove all AsNoTracking() and Update() method will only save changes, nothing changes - I receive the same error.

(Thanks for side note - I didn't consider it at all)

Comment: @VadimKurdesov you need to track all database objects if you want to make relations. And maybe disable explicit `Include` loading and make all your `ICollection`s virtual.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just tracking all entities didn't help, but lazy loading did. But I don't know why. Could you please explain, why result using Include() differs from using lazy loading?

Comment: @VadimKurdesov it shouldn't. Can you share your `GetAll` method?

Comment: Sure - updated question post. It just returns `DBSet`.

Comment: *why are you using Include, instead of lazy loading?* - but equally (possibly better) question could potentially be "why are you use by lazy loading instead of Include?". Lazy loading isn't necessarily better and can quickly descend into a performance nightmare if you don't appreciate what happens behind the scenes when you do what you do in code

Comment: @CaiusJard true, but I think in both cases you need to know what you are doing. I've seen production code where for every query all relationships were loaded. A 200 line query. That of course was also a gaint performance bottleneck.

Comment: @VadimKurdesov I added an example to my code

Comment: @JHBonarius, thanks for testing! I'll take a closer look at what the problem really was. Thanks again!